# AngularDart Dialog service

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I need to open a dialog (modal) in a component in an ngFor loop. I'm pretty sure repeating the modal inside my component is not the answer.

I'm looking for a way to have a Dialog Service in AngulatDart, in Angular2 (TS) I would do something like :

```
@Injectable()
export class MyDialogService {
  constructor(private dialog: MdDialog) {
  }

  public openDialog() {
    let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>;
    dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent);
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
}
```

I didn't find a way to do the same in AngularDart

Comment: What is the problem? Did you check the dialog or popup component in https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components

Comment: The problem is that I don't wan't to include my dialog into my component, so I may need to call a service for that.

Comment: I got that, but I don't understand yet what prevents you from doing that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What prevents me is that I don't know how :-) I can't find an equivalent to MdDialog/MdDialogRef in dart.

Comment: I don't know what they do because I never used Angular TS material components.

Comment: The question is, how to dynamically create & open a modal from a service in AngularDart ?

Comment: I'd provide a service globally (in AppComponent) and a component that displays dialogs and subscribes to that service, and other components that communicate with the dialog component using the service and pass component types or templates to be displayed by the dialog component.

Answer (score 1):

As Gunter mentioned, there is no provided "DialogService" in the set of AngularDart components. You could file a feature request, but I imagine creating such a service would be really easy - you could add a `<material-dialog>` in your root level component and expose your root component as an injectable service to show or hide it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Günter and matanlurey, I end up creating a simple service with a `LazyEventEmitter` to trigger the dialog :

### dialog_service.dart

```
@Injectable()
class DialogService {
  final LazyEventEmitter<bool> modalEvents = new LazyEventEmitter<bool>();

  DialogService() {
  }

  void openDialog() {
    modalEvents.add(true);
  }
}
```

The parent component (eg AppComponent) contains the Dialog component :

### dialog_component.html

```
<modal [(visible)]="showDialog">
  <material-dialog headered class="headered-dialog">
    [...]
  </material-dialog>
</modal>
```

### dialog_component.dart

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-dialog',
  styleUrls: const ['dialog_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'dialog_component.html',
  directives: const [materialDirectives],
  providers: const [materialProviders]
)
class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
  final DialogService _dialogService;
  bool showDialog = false;

  DialogComponent(this._dialogService);

  @override
  ngOnInit() {
    _dialogService.modalEvents.listen((showDialog) {
      this.showDialog = showDialog;
    });
  }
}
```